# Installing Thrift with Solandra

Tags: ubuntu, php, cassandra

I am trying to install Thrift with Solandra.

Normally when I just want to install Thrift with Cassandra, I followed this tutorial: https://wiki.fourkitchens.com/display/PF/Using+Cassandra+with+PHP

But how can I do the same for Solandra?

Thrift with PHP...

Using Ubuntu Server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually wrote that wiki page. :-)

So, I can interpret your question two ways:

1. How do I build a client to have PHP access Solandra?
2. How do I build a Cassandra Thrift client for PHP when I'm using Solandra?

For the first question, the answer is that Solandra uses HTTP for core management and Solr API access. You don't need a Thrift client (nor does Solandra support one). For an HTTP client, I recommend the cURL extension for PHP; it's included with most PHP builds these days.

For the second question, you would build the client the same way you do for normal Cassandra (as instructed on my wiki page). Just make sure you pull the same version of Cassandra that Solandra is using.